# Perform a segue with NO animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, swift, segue

Is it possible to perform an iOS segue but with NO animation whatsoever?  I haven't found any documentation indicating that it is, but I'd imagine that given the fact that there's an `animated:(BOOL)animated` property on practically every method in UIKit there must be some way to accomplish this.

We've got a simply UIViewController setup, and when the user presses a UIButton, I'd like to be able to perform the segue but with absolutely no animation.  Our existing code looks like this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject?) {
   self.performSegue("MySegue", sender: nil)
}
```

I haven't been able to find any way of preventing the Segue from animating, though.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could easily deactivate the Animation in your storyboard:

[image: Sotyboard]

Comment: Building for iOS8+ I get an error saying disabling segue animation is only available on iOS9. However, I only get this error when I choose "Show". Show Detail and Modal work without error flags.

Comment: Can I make it not animate with show or does segue have to be modal??

Answer (score 3):

On the button action add the following code:

```
TryViewController *trypage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Try"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:trypage animated:NO];
```

You just need to set the Storyboard ID of the view you want to go.
Storyboard ID can be found here:
[image]